# Passing input parameters correctly to a method

Tags: java

Below is my Interface:

```
public interface IDBClient {
    public String read(ClientInput input);
}
```

This is my implementation of the interface:

```
public class DatabaseClient implements IDBClient {

    @Override
    public String read(ClientInput input) {

    }
}
```

Now I have a factory which gets the instance of `DatabaseClient` like this:

```
IDBClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.getInstance();
....
```

Now I need to make a call to `read` method of my `DatabaseClient` which accepts the `ClientInput` parameter and below is the class for the same. This class was not written by me so that is the reason I am having a question on this and I am pretty much sure this is the wrong way of doing it.

```
public final class ClientInput {

    private Long userid;
    private Long clientid;
    private Long timeout_ms = 20L;
    private boolean debug;
    private Map<String, String> parameterMap;

    public ClientInput(Long userid, Long clientid, Map<String, String> parameterMap, Long timeout_ms, boolean debug) {
        this.userid = userid;
        this.clientid = clientid;
        this.parameterMap = parameterMap;
        this.timeout_ms = timeout_ms;
        this.debug = debug;
    }
}
```

So when customer make a call to `read` method of `DatabaseClient`, they will create the `ClientInput` parameter like this and then use the factory to get the Instance of `DatabaseClient` and then call the read method accordingly.

```
Map<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
paramMap.put("attribute", "segmentation");

ClientInput input = new ClientInput(109739281L, 20L, paramMap, 1000L, true);

IDBClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.getInstance();
client.read(input);
```

Is this the right way of creating the `ClientInput` and then passing it to the read method? If not, then what's the best way of doing it? Where should I be doing validation check to see whether the customer has passed valid user IDs or valid client ID, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no major concern with setting the values of `ClientInput` via the constructor. What is your concern with this anyway? My minor concerns are:

1. There are already three arguments of the Long type, it may not clear to other developers which position is for which field (especially during those long nights...).
2. If more inputs are required, it will make the constructor declaration longer.

Based on the name, I will prefer validation to be done within `ClientInput`. Oh, and it should have getter methods that your `IDBClient` implementations can use, and I'm guessing that's already the case as the fields are private.

On a related note, how else will `ClientInput` be used by `IDBClient`, besides the `read()` method?

Comment: Thanks hjk.. ClientInput will be used only to retrieve the various input parameters and use them to make a call and it will be used only at that place.. And I agree with both of your issues.. How can I avoid first issue? Should it be `long` instead of `Long` object. And regarding your second issue, do you think is there any way of avoiding this issue by some better way?

Comment: For the first issue, making it `long` or `Long` doesn't matter since the compiler will perform auto-boxing, and only a smart IDE (with the right settings) will prompt you about that. For both issues, consider just using setter methods for `ClientInput`. However, if you really go down this path, then you should re-evaluate why do you need a wrapper class just to 'hold' (layman terms) a bunch of input parameters together. You should consider @rolfl's answer too, if that's the case.

Answer (score 3):

Like most times, it is best to validate your data before you use it. In your case, since the input data needs to be validated by the Database infrastructure, I recommend adding it to the `IDBClient` interface.

I also assume that the `paramMap` is the `query` you want to run, and not part of the user/login information.

I suspect the logical thing to do is to extend your interface to look like:

```
public interface IDBClient {

    public interface SessionHandle extends AutoCloseable, Closeable {
        public boolean isAlive();
    }

    public SessionHandle createSession(Long userid, Long clientid,
              Long timeout_ms, boolean debug) throws InvalidLoginException;

    public String read(SessionHandle session, Map<String, String> parameterMap)
              throws ReadNotPossibleException, SessionExpiredException;
}
```

Now you are forced to create a `SessionHandle` instance that is pre-verified, and immutable. The content of that `SessionHandle` is whatever it needs to be for your actual `IDBClient` implementaton. The `IDBClient` implementation will know which handles are valid, and can do other things with the handle as needed.

Because times are good, and Java7 is better, you should also ensure that your `SessionHandle` [is `AutoCloseable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) so you can [use try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Your Exceptions ([which you should create custom versions of](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/creating.html)) for your interface should all extend a single Exception class, for example:

```
public DBClientException extends Exception { ..... }
public ReadNotPossibleException extends DBClientException {....}
public SessionExpiredException extends DBClientException {...}
```

by doing this, you can allow the user to catch just the database exception, or more-specific database exception sub-types if needed....

The 'user experience' will look like:

```
IDBClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.getInstance();
try (IDBClient.SessionHandle session =
          client.createSession( 109739281L, 20L, 1000L, true) ) {

    String result = client.read(session, paramMap);

} catch (DBClientException e) {
    .....
}
```